# Underscore.js map not working with new objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I am experiencing some very odd behavior with underscore.js `_.map` function.

It seems as though when I try to "new up" an object inside the function, it fails. But without a new object inside the function, it works as expected. Am I missing something here?

The following does not work (i.e. it prints nothing). It seems to be failing after the new object is created:

```
var test = { a: "test" };

var foo = _.map(data.A, function (dataItem) {
    var a = new test();

    console.log(a);
    return a;
});
```

But this does work:

```
var test = { a: "test" };

var foo = _.map(data.A, function (dataItem) {
    var a = dataItem;

    console.log(a);
    return a;
});
```

And the above logs all of the items in the data.A array.

Comment: it should be `Object.create(test)` not `new test`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't work is caused by these lines:

```
var test = { a: "test" };
```

and

```
var a = new test;
```

You have to declare test as a function:

```
var test = function () {
   return  { a: "test" };
}
```

in order to use the [new operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new).

The issue is not related with underscore.js or with the map function but with javascript in general.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an Underscore.js issue but more of a JavaScript object issue. Since `test` is an object literal, you'll need to use `Object.create()`. This will take `test` and make a new object

```
var a = Object.create(test);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ne9Yq/)

Reference: [Creating new objects using object literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9205136/creating-new-objects-using-object-literals)

MDN [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)***

*** If you don't have access to `Object.create` due to browser limitations, this MDN page has a polyfill function at the bottom.